# in_category method in wordpress and script tags - AdjacentHTML

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to show .gif banner on a posts only within specific category after first paragraph in wordpress, so I my code in loop-single.php looks like:

```
<?php if(in_category('my_category')){ ?>
<script>
    const par = document.querySelector('p');
    par.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div><a href="other_page" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="some_gif" alt="" class=""></a></div>')
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Anyone have an idea? Or may be some other solution that not recquires installing additional plugins (not that I don't want to, most of them just slow the site down).

Thank you

edit: 'after first paragraph' added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way, firstly I needed to check if the post is in wanted category, than create a function and call it afterwards. The code is set in single-loop.php file in my template:

```
<?php if(in_category('my-category')){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function krasAd() {
    const par = document.querySelector("p");
    par.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div><a href="some-url-target" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="my-gif" alt="" class=""></a></div>')
};
    krasAd();
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

There was also one way to check if you have a string in URL that only recquires JS. But it recquires you to have properly created URL structure, for example: domain.com/category/post

If I had category in my posts URL I would use code below, the code is set before closing footer tag in my single-loop.php template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("my-string") > -1) {
        const par = document.querySelector("p");
        par.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div><a href="some-target-url" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="my-gif" alt="" class=""></a></div>')
    }
</script>
```